# Give input to a Sencha 2 template

Tags: sencha-touch-2

How can I pass arguments to a Sencha 2 template? Below is my small template, have tried different things like defining "field variables" on the template and using the config, and so fourth, but Im definitly doing something wrong. Lets say I want to give arguments "title" and "usageTime", how can I do it

```
Ext.define('Sencha.templates.AppDetailsUsageTemplate' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.XTemplate',
    constructor: function (config) {
       var html = [
           '<div id="{id}" class="limitsList {cls}">',
           '   <div class="reportsSummaryLeft"> {title} </div>',
           '   <div class="reportsSummaryRight"> {usageTime}  </div>',
           '   <div style="clear:both"></div>',
           '</div>'];
       this.callParent(html);
    }
});
```

In my view I wanna do something ala this (pseudo code below):

```
xtype: 'container',
tpl: Ext.create('Sencha.templates.AppDetailsUsageTemplate',{
    title: 'test tittle',
    usageTime: 100384
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, give parameters through data:
Examples:

```
{
    id:     'appDetailsMonth',
    xtype:  'component',
    tpl:    Ext.create('Sencha.templates.AppDetailsUsageTemplate')
},{
    id:     'appDetailsLifeDuration',
    xtype:  'component',
    tpl:    Ext.create('Sencha.templates.AppDetailsUsageTemplate')
}
```

And then in applyItems

```
applyItems:function(newItems, oldItems) {
    var i    = 0,
        iNum = newItems.length,
        data = this.getData();

    var yesterdayItem = newItems[2];
    yesterdayItem.data = {
        title: 'Yesterday',
        usage: data.dayDuration
    };
    ....
}
```